# elasticsearch_dsl aggs 'top-hits' operation return dict instead of documents

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch-dsl

My elasticsearch_dsl version 6.3.1, and my code is like this:

---

```py
  s=MyDoc.search()
  s.aggs.bucket("top_recommends", "terms", field="recommend_name",
  order={"_count": "desc"}).metric("top_hit_three", "top_hits", size=3)
```

But the result returned is a dict in `response.aggregations.top_recommends.buckets`, what it should contain is a bucket that contains instances of MyDoc. Is this a bug of the elasticsearch_dsl?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something wrong with your setup, this works in the test suite as you can see at https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/test_elasticsearch_dsl/test_integration/test_search.py#L43-L53

If it doesn't work for you it could indeed be a bug, could you please submit an issue with a way to replicate? Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry but my company had forbidden github commit. but I can descript it here.

Comment: s = MyDoc.search(index=user_input,)
intent_filter = ~Q('terms', intent__raw=black_intents)

input_query = Q('match', user_said=input_key_words) & ~Q('term', user_said=input_key_words)

s =s.filter(intent_filter).query(input_query)

s.aggs.bucket("top_recommends", "terms", field="intent.raw", order={"_count": "desc"}).metric("top_hit_three", "top_hits", size=3)

return s.execute()

The response is strange. I can not use “”if response“ on it, Becase "if response" return false even there are  buckets  in the response. Then when I access the bucket documents, they are dict, not objects.

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot help you, it works in the code, it works in the test and even this code cannot reproduce it for me. Opening an issue from github is not any different than posting on SO so I would please urge you to reconsider as that is really where this belongs.

Comment: The middle path access are always document object, it is there we should access as type of list and dict:

query_response.aggregations.top_recommends.buckets[0].top_hit_three.hits.hits.
The last "hits" is of python normal type list but not  "elasticsearch_dsl.utils.AttrList", then all documents inside are dict instead of document objects.

Comment: @HenryJohn please have a loot at the link I sent which shows how it all can work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Honza,
  Thanks for your help. I found the reason.
In your test  function "def test_top_hits_are_wrapped_in_response(data_client)", access to aggs result is as follows:

```
hits = [h for h in top_commits.hits]
# Test code
print(type(hits))
print(type(hits[0]))
```

and the output is

```
<class 'elasticsearch_dsl.utils.AttrList'>
<class 'es.es_models.QuestionIntent'>
```

But my code is just like that:

```
hits = top_commits.hits.hits
print(type(hits))
print(type(hits[0])
```

and the output is:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'dict'>
```

It seems that there is an "hits" attribute in the "top_commits.hits" object list. I suggest that this attribute should be shield if you do not want to provide it for public usage. Any way, I had thought I should access the aggs result object path just like which displayed in ES search result json path, and so I got into a mistake result access method.